# Equal is not equal in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm using a [shell script](https://github.com/deanc/wordpress-plugin-git-svn) to deploy my plugins to the WordPress repo.

While this works in most cases some plugins fail. The problem is when the script checks for the version number and compare the readme.txt with the actual plugin file [[Source](https://github.com/deanc/wordpress-plugin-git-svn/blob/master/deploy.sh#L22)].

Example output:

```
readme version: 0.5
plugin.php version: 0.5
Versions don't match. Exiting....
```

I can just remove the check but I would like to have just for its initial purpose.

So why is `0.5 != 0.5`? is this a wrong type?

**EDIT:**

This is the part of the script

```
# Check version in readme.txt is the same as plugin file
NEWVERSION1=`grep "^Stable tag" $GITPATH/readme.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $3}'`
echo "readme version: $NEWVERSION1"
NEWVERSION2=`grep "^Version" $GITPATH/$MAINFILE | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`
echo "$MAINFILE version: $NEWVERSION2"

if [ "$NEWVERSION1" != "$NEWVERSION2" ]; then echo "Versions don't match $NEWVERSION1 != $NEWVERSION2. Exiting...."; exit 1; fi
```

**Update**

When doing

```
if [ "$NEWVERSION1" != "$NEWVERSION2" ]; then echo "Versions don't match $NEWVERSION1# != $NEWVERSION2#. Exiting...."; exit 1; fi
```

i get as output

```
#. Exiting.... match 0.5# != 0.5
```

so the '#' is at the beginning.

Comment: Rather than linking to an external script, it'd be more useful for you to provide us with a minimal script that reproduces the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: thanks, I missed that.

Comment: I suspect that there's some additional spaces somewhere. Try adding a `set -x` to the script to see the values that are being compared.

Comment: Whitespace? add some marker to your output, e.g. `echo "readme version: $NEWVERSION1#"`

Comment: I've updated my questions with your input

Comment: BTW, if your shell is bash, running with `set -x` would have made this obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#. Exiting.... match 0.5# != 0.5
```

Your second value contains a `\r` which will move the cursor to the beginning of the line, hence the output.

```
echo -e "abc\rd"   # dbc
```

Strip it with `| tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: The place where you store it in the variable, inside command substitution.